# Firebase App Hangs At Test Phase In Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-build

[Cross-posting from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/dw66t2/firebase_app_hangs_in_google_cloud_build/), but in summary- I'm trying to setup a React app using Firestore for data storage and GCB for CI/CD. However, GCB hangs in the testing phase when I push new code using Firestore.

I've done some basic debugging-

- It hangs when I try *reading* from Firestore, but in [this commit](https://github.com/darthbob88/raymond-project-list/pull/3/commits/7e62a09acf5c6f9cf8ec683584dcb097b8e5d2a3), where I only *write* data, it built just fine.
- In [the tests I added](https://github.com/darthbob88/raymond-project-list/blob/d6a0acd4ddf583167e216fa53c698956bbd8328b/src/models/IdeasService.test.ts) to check my interaction with Firestore, they all passed and [the build log](https://pastebin.com/zQigERWv) showed that it was able to read from Firestore just fine. It just, y'know, doesn't go anywhere after that.

```
Step #1: > react-scripts test --watchAll=false --detectOpenHandles
Step #1:
Step #1: PASS src/IdeaTable/IdeaTable.test.tsx
Step #1: PASS src/models/IdeasService.test.ts
Step #1:   â— Console
Step #1:
Step #1:     console.log src/models/IdeasService.test.ts:6
Step #1:       [ { description: 'Set up personal website, mostly for this but also for hosting Calibre',
Step #1:           slug: 'setup-portfolio',
Step #1:           summary: 'Set up portfolio',
Step #1:           id: 'wvQOj2m3zFNpwvdZVAnr' }]
Step #1:
Step #1: PASS src/App.test.tsx
Step #1:
Step #1: Test Suites: 3 passed, 3 total
Step #1: Tests:       5 passed, 5 total
Step #1: Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Step #1: Time:        5.115s
Step #1: Ran all test suites.
```

As noted in that Reddit post, my current best hypothesis is that this issue is caused by the connection to Firebase staying open and keeping things from finishing, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: It would be useful if you shared the build log of the commit that was successful, additionally, it seems that you are correct based on the output of the log you shared, maybe the information [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data) could be useful for getting the information from Firestore.

Comment: Sorry, [here's the build logs](https://pastebin.com/rPgEHYsU) for [this commit](https://github.com/darthbob88/raymond-project-list/commit/7e62a09acf5c6f9cf8ec683584dcb097b8e5d2a3).

Comment: And I'm already using the "get all documents" method from that link, but the "get exactly one document" might help show what's going wrong, and would definitely be useful.

Comment: You might wanna debug the build, are you manually triggering the build with a gcloud commmand, or are you triggering it differently? if you are using gcloud, I would suggest using the ["--verbosity="debug""](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/#--verbosity) flag on the command just so you can guarantee that the issue is due to connectivity and not something else. You might wanna update the logs you shared afterwards.

Comment: I try not to manually run builds if I can. These are all triggered automatically from Github, by either commits to master branch or pull requests.

Just submitted a build with that flag, and [nothing useful](https://pastebin.com/9mnqE9qU). All tests pass, and then build times out.

Comment: OK this is interesting. I've confirmed that if I specifically skip the App.test.tsx, or if I remove the IdeaListPage element that uses Firestore, everything works fine. I'm beginning to think it's a problem with the fact that the test unmounts <App>, but doesn't disconnect from Firebase.

Comment: I have cloned your repository and manually triggering the build did not give me any issue, maybe you should try running it manually once in order to test through something like Cloud Shell just to test if it's a connectivity issue.